# SPARQL on REGEX filter name

Tags: regex, sparql

SPARQL on REGEX filter name works when I use direct search query. It is not working on regex using query.

```sql
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://dublincore.org/2010/10/11/dcterms.rdf#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX grs: <http://www.georss.org/georss/point>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select distinct ?iri ?logo ?description 
  {
    values ?hasLogo { foaf:depiction dbpedia-owl:thumbnail }
    values ?hasName { foaf:name rdfs:label }
    ?iri a                    dbpedia-owl:Company ;
         dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description ;
         filter(regex(?Name, "Lufthansa", "i" )) ;
        ?hasLogo              ?logo .
        filter( langMatches(lang(?description),"en") )
    }
```

Above code was not working because of `filter(regex(?Name, "Lufthansa", "i" )) ;`

If I used direct search `?Name "Lufthansa"@en ;` it works fine.

Why is this?

Comment: At the risk of changing your query, I've fixed some markup, and changed some whitespace. You don't need to escape `< >` within code blocks. Please confirm that your query is as now shown.

Comment: Your varible `?Name` is not bound to anything outside the filter. The whole triple pattern with the name properties is missing.

Comment: And it would be good to be more specific instead of saying "not working". What does not work? Errors? Not the expected resultset? ...

Answer (score 3):

Try running your query through the [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/validate/query).  It's not legal.  It looks like you want the following.  You still have to get the variable bindings in the usual way.  Only then can you add the additional filter.  You can't just put a filter expression in place of (part of) a triple pattern.

```sql
select distinct ?iri ?logo ?description  {
  values ?hasLogo { foaf:depiction dbpedia-owl:thumbnail }
  values ?hasName { foaf:name rdfs:label }
  ?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
       dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description ;
       ?hasName ?Name ;
       ?hasLogo ?logo .

  filter langMatches(lang(?description),"en")
  filter(regex(?Name, "Lufthansa", "i" )) ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct ?iri ?name ?description {
?iri a dbpedia-owl:Company ;
rdfs:label ?label ;
foaf:name ?name ;
dbpedia-owl:abstract ?description .
#foaf:depiction|dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?logo .
filter(regex(?name, "\\blufthansa\\b","i" )) .
filter(regex(?label, "\\blufthansa\\b","i" ))
# filter( langMatches(lang(?description),"en") )
}
limit 100
```