# Search for a specific programming language from DBPedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I can list programming languages from dbpedia but If I want to just search for specific programming language then thats a problem. Because some programming languages are in dbpedia like `"pyhton (Programming language)"@en` and another is `"C++"@en`. Now the problem is I just want to search by their name like `python` or may be `C++` but some of them have `(programming language)"@en` or `@en` attached with them. How can I write a query to search only by their name?

Comment: Try using `FILTER` with `REGEX` ... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413155/sparql-on-regex-filter-name

Comment: I tried with regex but its not working

Comment: it works for sure...`SELECT  ?pl 
WHERE
  { ?pl  a  dbo:ProgrammingLanguage ;
         rdfs:label  ?pl_label
    FILTER ( lang(?pl_label) = "en" )
    filter(regex(str(?pl_label), "python", "i"))
}`

Comment: as well as with `SELECT  ?pl 
WHERE
  { ?pl  a  dbo:ProgrammingLanguage ;
         rdfs:label  ?pl_label
    FILTER ( lang(?pl_label) = "en" )
    ?pl_label bif:contains '"python"'
}`

Comment: And yes, the difference is that `bif:contains` does not do substring matching, i.e. only whole words after some tokenizer process will be checked for matches. That's why the second query does not return `http://dbpedia.org/resource/IronPython`

Comment: @shajedul-islam-any, be careful to properly ``escape`` special characters when using regular expressions. E.g. for `c++`, you should write something like ``"c\\+\\+"``

Comment: @AKSW your queries indeed seem to work. Can you write them as an answer, so that the question poster can mark it as an accepted answer?